# How to read data from Console and run it using selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

```
List <WebElement> lst=fd.findElements(By.tagName("loc"));       
System.out.println(lst.size());    
for(int i=0;i<lst.size()-1;i++){

    System.out.println(lst.get(i).getText());    
    Thread.sleep(3000);    
    fd.navigate().to(lst.get(i).getText());    
    Thread.sleep(30000);    
    System.out.println(fd.getTitle());    
}
```

Comment: for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++)

Comment: What are you trying to do? If it's just take parameters from the command line then google that topic and I guarantee you'll find it, it is basic programming and not specific to Selenium at all

Comment: i am trying to get all urls present under <loc/>.so i used List for that.now i want to open those urls which was printed in console

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do some basic tutorials in whatever programming language you're using (Java?)

1. You are printing the values to the console - you already know the value! You don't need to read it from the console again.
2. Problem with your Selenium approach - opening all links in a loop like I think you're trying to do it problematic, since once you open the first link then your List of remaining links becomes stale (the links are not on the page anymore). Questions like this have been asked countless times on SO, so search around after doing a little more investigation.
3. Research [how to ask better questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), to avoid those pesky down votes & so everyone knows what you're talking about